# Swagger results with `TypeError: Failed to fetch` for .net core RedirectResult

Tags: redirect, .net-core, swagger

I have .net core WebApi application setup with swagger. An endpoint that responses with RedirectResult is not handled by swagger ui and shown up as Undocumented: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

The redirect result itself contains a SAS url to Azure Storage Blob file.
I've tried to call this endpoint with SoapUI and Postman and the actual file appeared in response with `application/octet-stream` content type

The endpoint is built in format

```
Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
   ...
   return Redirect(blobSasUri)
}
```

There is support for that or even some workaround or I've missed something?